# How to keep a chain processing going referring to unnamed outputs in an intermediate process in R?

Tags: r, pipe, pipeline, chaining, magrittr

I'm trying to connect multiple processes with the native pipe `|>` in R.

In the following MWE,

1. I give the data frame `iris` to the first and second process simultaneously in `(\(x){...})()`;
2. In `(\(x){...})()`, the output of the first process is named as `setosa.Sepal.Length.np` and that of the second process is named as `versicolor.Sepal.Length.np` by the double arrow assignment operator `->>`;
3. The correlation between the data of these two outputs is calculated with `cor()`, and ***this calculation is not directly connected to the previous chain-process***.

```r
iris |>
  (\(x){
    ## First process
    filter(
      x,
      Species == "setosa"
      ) |>
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length) ->>
    setosa.Sepal.Length.np

    ## Second process    
    filter(
      x,
      Species == "versicolor"
      ) |>
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length) ->>
    versicolor.Sepal.Length.np
  })()

cor(setosa.Sepal.Length.np, versicolor.Sepal.Length.np)
```

***I want to directly connect the process of correlation calculation to the previous processes with `|>`***. To do so, I have to remain the output of the first and second process unnamed, and I must not create the object `setosa.Sepal.Length.np` and `versicolor.Sepal.Length.np`. However, how should I refer to the output of the first and second process, then?

```r
iris |>
  (\(x){
    filter(
      x,
      Species == "setosa"
      ) %>%
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length) # remain the first output unnamed

    filter(
      x,
      Species == "versicolor"
      ) %>%
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length) # remain the second output unnamed
  })() |>                       # send the outputs in this process to the next `cor()`
  cor(????, ????)               # How should I refer to the first and second output here?
```

## Supplement code

The first MWE is equivalent to the following codes with `magrittr`'s `%>%`.

```r
require(magrittr)
iris %>%
  {
    filter(
      .,
      Species == "setosa"
      ) %>%
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length) ->>
    setosa.Sepal.Length

    filter(
      .,
      Species == "versicolor"
      ) %>%
    dplyr::select(Sepal.Length) ->>
    versicolor.Sepal.Length
  }

cor(setosa.Sepal.Length, versicolor.Sepal.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the native pipe you can only pipe values into the first parameter. You can never pipe values into the second parameter of `cor()`. There's just no way to do that. You'd need an intermediate function that could take a list of values and return a list from the previous step. For example here we can create a helper function `corlist` to accept the list.

```
corlist <- function(x) cor(x[[1]], x[[2]])
iris |>
  (\(x){
    list(
      filter(
        x,
        Species == "setosa"
      ) %>%
        dplyr::select(Sepal.Length),
      filter(
        x,
        Species == "versicolor"
      ) %>%
        dplyr::select(Sepal.Length)
    )
  })() |> 
  corlist()
#              Sepal.Length
# Sepal.Length  -0.08084973
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must call variable names specifically, one possible way using `with`

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>% {
  list(
    subset(., Species == 'setosa', select = 'Sepal.Length') %>%
                                   rename(., 'setosa.Sepal.Length' = 'Sepal.Length'),
    subset(., Species == 'versicolor', select = 'Sepal.Length') %>% 
                                   rename(., 'versicolor.Sepal.Length' = 'Sepal.Length')
  )
} %>%
  do.call(cbind, .) %>% with(., cor(setosa.Sepal.Length, versicolor.Sepal.Length))
```

If only `cor` is necessary, can codegolf this a bit and avoid use of `dplyr`:

```r
iris %>% {
  list(
    subset(., Species == 'setosa', select = 'Sepal.Length'),
    subset(., Species == 'versicolor', select = 'Sepal.Length')
  )
} %>%
  do.call(cbind, .) %>% cor                # or {cor(.[,1],.[,2])} although less elegant
```